# Custom api for User login magento Invalid Api path

Tags: magento-1.7, module, login

Hi I am developing android app using magento api. I am using built-in api for some of the tasks. Like getting the products for different category etc. 
As I need some customized api for user login, Sort and filter products etc.
I followed [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785) its working for getting products. But I need to change this one for user login by taking user credentials. Please let me know what changes I need to do with this code for V2Soap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921695/magento-xmlconnect-what-is-it-and-how-can-i-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customized api for user login:

Api.php :

```
public function customerlogin($user,$pass)
  {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
        try
        {
            $session->login( $user, $pass);
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();
            $quoteCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
            $quoteCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
            $quoteCollection->addOrder('updated_at');
            $quote = $quoteCollection->getFirstItem();

            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'valid', 'userData' => $customer->getId() , 'quoteID' =>  $quote->getData() ));
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'userData' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
  }
```

Android :

```
   SoapSerializationEnvelope  env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    env.dotNet = false;
                    env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                    env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

                    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Customerlogin");
                    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
                    request.addProperty("user", mailid);
                    request.addProperty("pass", passworf);

                     env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                 String result = androidHttpTransport.call("", env, headerPropertyArrayList).getResponse().toString();
```